# php shortcode html output

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, shortcode

I have a plugin which uses this shortcode: `[daisy]`

And the html output of this shortcode is : `<a class="clickable">Click Here</a>`
Plugin is working perfect if I use the shortcode to trigger the plugin. It works with this also:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[daisy]'); ?>`

Normally it should work also with the

`<a class="clickable">Click Here</a>` directly but it's not working, the link appears but if I click on it nothing happens.
This shortcode triggers some javascript to load :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Init Plugin
        $(".clickable").contactpopup({
            'style' : '<?php echo $wp_cpup_theme; ?>',
            'bgcolor' : '<?php echo $wp_cpup_color; ?>',
            'formelement' : '#Form_PopContactUs',
            'effect' : '<?php echo $wp_cpup_effect; ?>',
            'header' : '<?php echo $wp_cpup_popup_title; ?>'
        });
    });
</script>
```

So, it should work fine also with the html.

Any ideas why if I click the `<a>` element is working and if I use
 `<?php echo do_shortcode('[daisy]'); ?>` it's triggering the plugin (contact form popup).

[Here](http://themes.thevda.com/wordpress/contact-popup/) is the demo with the contact form if you want to take a look.

Any suggestions ?

Handler for shortcode:

```
/*--------------------------------
               Shortcode
    ----------------------------------*/
    add_shortcode("daisy", "wp_contact_popup_short_code_handler");

    function wp_contact_popup_short_code_handler() {
      $demolph_output = wp_contact_popup_short_code_posts_function();
      return $demolph_output;
    }

    function wp_contact_popup_short_code_posts_function( $content = null ) {
        // Grab Globals
        global $wp_cpup_popup_link;
        global $wp_cpup_popup_email;
        global $wp_cpup_popup_thanks;
        global $wp_cpup_form_html;
        global $wp_cpup_email_message;

        ?>
```

Comment: It sounds like the shortcode is responsible for injecting the javascript into the page. Without knowing what plugin it is it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'm guessing the shortcode handler does something besides just setting up that javascript - defining contactpopup() maybe? Can you post the whole handler? Are you getting any javascript errors? Also, you should add the "wordpress" tag or add it to the subject of your question

Comment: @moopet It looks like it's http://codecanyon.net/item/daisy-fancy-popup-contact-forms/2417056 (not free)

Comment: @dearlbry, I've updated the post with the shortcode handler, and I'm not getting any javascript errors

Comment: you can test it also [here](http://whiteandgold.ro/ipp/blog/) and click on "Click here" and you will see that the plugin is triggering just the header part and when I'm using the shortcode it triggers the input fields also.